# concatenate models with weighting or leave seperate for manual weighting?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have 2 models I am training, one for each column of data in my dataset.
It seems 1 model is fairly accurate in its results so I want to give it a better weight in determining the actual outputs.

I do not know if I should be trying to concatenate these to models and somehow provide the weights using something like a Rescaling layer in keras OR if I should leave them separate then just do my own processing after?
What are the pro's and con's of each?

```
def get_model(n_inputs_1, n_inputs_2, n_outputs):
    DENSE_LAYER_SIZE = 20
    inp1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_inputs_1,))
    de1 = keras.layers.Dense(DENSE_LAYER_SIZE, activation='relu')(inp1) #
    dr1 = keras.layers.Dropout(.2)(de1)

    inp2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_inputs_2,))
    de2 = keras.layers.Dense(DENSE_LAYER_SIZE, activation='relu')(inp2) #
    dr2 = keras.layers.Dropout(.2)(de2)

    rs2 = keras.layers.Rescaling(0.01)(dr2) # reduce impact of input 2 - is this ok?
    conc = keras.layers.Concatenate()([dr1, rs2])

    out = keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid')(conc)
    model = keras.models.Model([inp1, inp2], out)
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    return model
```

[Full code here](https://github.com/bit-shift-io/machine-learning-experiments/blob/master/netlifx-categorizer/train2.py)

Comment: Do you want to concatenate with respect to what? Layers? or do want to share the weights of the 1st model with other?

Comment: I have 2 input layers, 1 for each column of data. I am mapping 2 categories (my 2 inputs) to a set of tv shows in order for the model to self categories my data set so I can try to find similar tv shows.

BUT, I want to weight the data from the 2 input columns differently as "similar" shows is open to interpretation. So for example, the categories of a TV show might be more important than say the description or the run length of a tv show in determining how similar they are, hence I need some kinda of weighting. How should I implement this weighting?